# COUNTIFS - How to count values that match up criteria of LEFT(Searched_Column,2) > 6

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a set of values in a column

```
16.00_00.00_I
06.00_14.00_I
06.00_14.00_I
06.00_14.00_I
06.00_14.00_I
06.00_14.00_I
16.00_00.00_I
```

I would like to use COUNTIFS formula to count values that match a criteria of LEFT(Column,2) > 6 so it outputs 2 because there are two values that start with a number 16. I need it in one formula without any auxillary columns.

Comment: LEFT returns string value. You could try and change it to `...LEFT(Column,2)*1 > 6....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((--LEFT(A1:A7,2))>6))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can add second condition based on the last character = "I"?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((--LEFT(A1:A7,2)>6)*(RIGHT(A1:A7,1)="I"))` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNTIF` also:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,">07*")
```

Only here it is not possible to use `>06*`, because `06.00...` is already greater than that, so we add 1.

[image]